# Data format for Stanford POS-tagger

Tags: stanford-nlp, dataformat

I am re-training the Stanford POS-tagger on my own data. I have trained two other taggers on the same data in the following one-token-per-line format:

```
word1_TAG
word2_TAG
word3_TAG
word4_TAG
.
```

Is this format ok for the Stanford tagger, or does it need to be one-sentence-per-line?

```
word1_TAG word2_TAG word3_TAG word4_TAG .
```

Could using the first format for training and testing affect Stanford tagging results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have one sentence per line (your second example).

Using the first format will certainly affect tagging results: you'll effectively build a unigram tagger, in which all tagging is done without any sentence context at all.

Comment: Hi Teresa—if this resolves your question, please mark the answer as "accepted" using the green check mark on the left. Thanks!